# Single sign-on for Silverlight 4 app and web application

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have 2 different applications, one is in Silverlight and another is a web application.

I need single sign-on for both.

Scenario is like: any user logged-in to the Silverlight application then there is a menu in that app to open the other web application in logged-in mode.

Both applications have different databases but the user name and password are same in both.

I am using the WCF services for the silverlight application.

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use one DB for keep current session's token for each logged user. In this case isn't important where you logged you will take log-in token from this db.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using ASP.NET and Forms/other authentication and the Silverlight app is from the same web server.

first look at this link and the Silverlight Business application template from Visual Studio:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449(v=VS.91).aspx

A more manual approach could include writing a WCF service that returns or sets the "UserToken" that you store in session on a successful login.

```
// the wcf service needs these attributes
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]

// a manual approach: successful login, create a webservice method to call from Silverlight to set the authentication
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("currentUserToken", userToken);
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.EmailAddressUserControl1.EmailAddressTextBox.Text, false);
```

Forms Authentication will take care of logging you out on ASP.Net requests, but you'll have 
to handle session timeouts one service requests yourself.